# Prevent CAGradientLayer locations from returning to original values after using CABasicAnimation

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation, cabasicanimation, cagradientlayer

I'm trying to make a gradient animate so that the locations of the two colors shift from left to right.  The problems is that once the animation completes, the gradient locations snap back to their original position.

Here is my playground code:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class MyViewController : UIViewController {

  let gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer = {
    let layer = CAGradientLayer()
    layer.colors = [ UIColor.red.cgColor, UIColor.blue.cgColor ]
    layer.locations = [0.0, 0.5]
    layer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0)
    layer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)

    return layer
  }()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
    gradientLayer.frame = view.bounds

    let gradientChangeAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "locations")
    gradientChangeAnimation.duration = 1
    gradientChangeAnimation.toValue = [0.5, 1.0]
    gradientLayer.add(gradientChangeAnimation, forKey: nil)

  }

  override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    gradientLayer.frame = view.frame
  }
}

// Present the view controller in the Live View window
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = MyViewController()
```

How do I prevent the reset of the locations after the animation completes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just tell it to not remove on completion and set the locations to the new values:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
    gradientLayer.frame = view.bounds

    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction. setCompletionBlock {
        gradientLayer.locations = [0.5, 1.0]
        gradientLayer.removeAllAnimations()
    }

    let gradientChangeAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "locations")
    gradientChangeAnimation.duration = 1
    gradientChangeAnimation.toValue = [0.5, 1.0]
    gradientLayer.add(gradientChangeAnimation, forKey: nil)

    CATransaction.commit()
}
```

or set the **fillMode** and **isRemovedOnCompletion** properties appropriately.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
    gradientLayer.frame = view.bounds

    let gradientChangeAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "locations")
    gradientChangeAnimation.duration = 1
    gradientChangeAnimation.toValue = [0.5, 1.0]
    gradientChangeAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
    gradientChangeAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    gradientLayer.add(gradientChangeAnimation, forKey: nil)
}
```

Comment: Personally, I like the last solution because it has a completion block.. but it's all preference and needs. Decide on your own which suits you best..

Comment: I tried the first solution already but it doesn't work.  I'll give the other 2 solutions a try.  Stay tuned...

Comment: Last solution is the only one that works. I'll go ahead mark it as correct.  Thanks!

Comment: @DJSK; Weird.. the other solutions have worked for me in the past (still works in some of my current projects), hence why I added them. Well at least now I know the last will always work in every case/project.

Comment: Yeah I am not sure why either. Very weird.

Comment: so I figured out why the other solution wouldn't work.  The 'fillMode' parameter was missing.  It has to be set to forwards in addition to the 'isRemovedOnCompletion' parameter so that the animation is not removed on completion by default. I'll edit the answer to include it.